# Unexpected text found in layout file: """

Tags: android, xml

I am getting warning **(Unexpected text found in layout file: """)** at 1st AutoCompleteTextView. I think there is a problem in Relative layout because when i remove text view I get the same error but don't know what is going on... :(  I have tried a lot but got disappointment. Please help me to fix this....here is my xml code:

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"

    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/from"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/from"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#588810"/>



    <AutoCompleteTextView
         android:id="@+id/from_station"
         android:layout_below="@id/from"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
         android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
         android:hint="@string/hint_from"
         android:ems="10" >
    </AutoCompleteTextView>
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/to"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/from_station"
        android:text="@string/to"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#588810"/>

   <AutoCompleteTextView
       android:id="@+id/to_station"
       android:layout_below="@id/to"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
       android:hint="@string/hint_to"
       android:ems="0" 
       android:textColor="#588810">
   </AutoCompleteTextView>

</RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: post full layout code

Comment: There is no error in this xml.

Comment: you mentioned `autocompletetextview`..there is no `autocompletetextview` in this layout

Comment: Your xml is just fine.Just check in your `strings.xml` what you have placed against `android:text="@string/from"`

Comment: check this @string/hint_from if you have problem in autocomplete textview

Comment: are you closing the scrollview ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse, next time just clean your project:

Project → Clean

and it's solved! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have forgotten to close your ScrollView :

```
   ...
   android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
   android:hint="@string/hint_to"
   android:ems="0" 
   android:textColor="#588810">
   </AutoCompleteTextView>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I think that he's properly closing all the tags.

Comment: oh! When i put an extra double quotation mark anywhere outside the tag then it gives the same warning. Then when i remove the ("), the error disappears and my problem is solved. but i don't know why the problem has been occurred. its really surprising... :D And thanks everyone for reply.

Comment: A XML has to respect a particular format, you can have only one String per attribute.